# How to determine that the synchronization completed SymmetricDS

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, symmetricds

I need to write code, that uses SymmetricDS and synchronizes two DBs when one presses the button. I.e. I need to press the button, it shows that it is synching, then when there are no more changes it says 'Everything is ok' and lets me continue operations.

I've worked out all I need to do for that, except the way to determine that everything is synched.

The SymmetricDS engines are deployed in Tomcat 8, my application is deployed there too and I use JMX MBeans to connect to SymmetricDS to start/stop synchronization.

Comment: Hm, I don't think you need at all to start/stop the synchronization. Let it running in the background. To see if all data has been sent to the target database issue `select count(*) from sym_outgoing_batch sob where sob.status = 'OK'` and wait until it dropped to 0..

Comment: For the incoming data issue the same query replacing `sym_outgoing_batch` with `sym_incoming_batch`.

Comment: No, the thing is that I'm explicitely required to do that. It's gonna be used via very bad to none Internet connection, so that when a user can get to a place with Internet, he presses the button to sync all that happened, make sure that he did and go to places without internet again

Comment: Do I query database using JDBC or does SymmetricDS has some functions to cover that in JMX?

Comment: If there's an internet connection SymmetricDs will sync, if there's no it will keep retrying. No need explicitly to start/stop it. A custom JMX bean can be written to run these queries. It's much easier to query the database using JDBC or whatever language/platform used by the main application.

Comment: Well, the client wants it done that way, what can I do?) I have to find a way to implement that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71268/discussion-between-boris-pavlovic-and-smsk).

Comment: @SMSk : have you find any solution of this question? because i want to do the same in my application.i am not getting start and completion event of sync.please let me know if you find any solution.it would be great help.

Comment: @Biginner yes, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that these four queries

```
String serv_outgoing = "select * from sym_outgoing_batch where node_id = '" + node_id + "' and channel_id != 'config' and status != 'OK';";
String serv_data = "select d.* from sym_data d where d.data_id not in (select e.data_id from sym_data_event e);";

String client_outgoing = "select * from sym_outgoing_batch where node_id = '000' and channel_id != 'config' and status != 'OK';";
String client_data = "select d.* from sym_data d where d.data_id not in (select e.data_id from sym_data_event e);";
```

should return empty results. First two are executed on server database, the second two on client.

This doesn't look like a good solution, since the client has to have an access to the server database, but you can, for example, create a servlet on your server that listens to some HTTP request like "does server think that the sync is finished" and query it before checking client-side database

Also, this is an old piece of code, you should not use plain queries to coonect over JDBC and use Hibernate, or other ORMs, so they escape your parameters correctly and you're not prone to SQL injections (here of course you probably are generating `node_id` internally, but who knows, maybe you let users input it in some way, like a login or something)